# javascript schedule time range picker with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, range, schedule

I would like to use [this javascript time range script](http://www.columbia.edu/~dl415/web_design/javascript/time-range_selector.html), but adapted with half hours and all day hours (00:00,...,23:00,23:30). It could be done using the same javascript, but the html will be big and the timetable too wide.

How would you do it simpler? With Jquery? (some code needed, not just an answer)

The idea is to use this script to select working hours of a company and submit them through a form. It needs the possibility to use (at least) half hours and not to be very wide (draggable?).
You should be able to select the time range for every day, and as the original script, you should be able to select different periods of time for each day (8:00 to 14:00, 16:00 to 20:00,...).

I think that it's not very complicated to adapt for the expert people here and it's something very useful for a lot of people.